# An nWoD mage adding/removing a supernatural template?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

Mages in the new World of Darkness are able to manipulate reality to a fundamental level (depending on their depth of knowledge and abilities.)

**Can a mage bestow a supernatural template on a normal human being, or remove a supernatural template that someone already has?**

In other words: can a mage turn a normal person into a vampire, a werewolf, *a mage* (practically awakening a Sleeper), etc? And, in reverse, can a mage turn a vampire, a werewolf, etc back into a normal, ordinary human being? My *guess* is that yes, a mage is able to do this - question is, what Arcana and what level of power and knowledge allows it.

Am I right to suppose the above? (If so, where do I find the rules or implied rules for this?) If not, why not?

Please, cite official sources, if possible. (I'd be most interested in "non-god-machine" answers, since I'm still not really familiar with that edition.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You need to be an archmaster to do it.

**Imperial Mysteries** has the rules for it — it's a seven dot Arcana effect (p.35) and the Arcana required vary with the kind of supernatural and the degree of change required. Manipulating the vampire template requires Death, for example; werewolves require Life and Spirit, and to affect mages, you need both of their path's Ruling Arcana. (Changing a Mage from one path to another requires seven dots in all four Arcana -- a feat possible only at Gnosis 10.)

It is possible to Awaken a sleeper this way by granting them a path, but the book calls that a Wisdom 1 sin and says it's more likely to make a Banisher than a functional mage.

@Oxinabox points out that messing with greater templates attracts attention from hostile entities. That's true, too:

> All supernatural beings with greater templates and some
>   with lesser templates have sponsors in the Ascension War
>   who actively prevent archmages from meddling with their
>   agents. These entities will sometimes, if sought out and
>   bargained with, permit an archmaster to transform a human
>   into one of their charges, but strongly resist attempts
>   to alter the powers of their creation. For example, rumor
>   has it that archmages of Death have inflicted the curse of
>   vampirism in the past, but no one has cured that curse except
>   in legend and no one has ever undone the First Change of
>   a werewolf.